# par2tbb fails to compile with an "auto_ptr is not a member of std" error

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am trying to compile [par2tbb](https://github.com/chrsigg/par2tbb) on Gentoo Linux kernel 3.18.12, and I keep getting the following compilation error:

```
par2cmdline.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
par2cmdline.cpp:88:3: error: ‘auto_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
   std::auto_ptr<CommandLine> commandline(new CommandLine);
   ^
```

I already checked that `#include <memory.h>` was present on the source code, I already added `CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11` to the makefile, and it still won't compile.

Looking up online, these two measures are the only fixes I could find. Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated as of C++11, but I can't imagine that would cause a compilation error. Which compiler are you using? Also, I don't see the line `#include <memory.h>` in [the file causing the error](https://github.com/chrsigg/par2tbb/blob/master/par2cmdline.cpp).

Comment: It is <memory> not <memory.h> for C++

Comment: @RedRoboHood the line is in `par2cmdline.h`, which is included in the file causing the error.

Comment: [As you'll note](https://github.com/chrsigg/par2tbb/blob/master/par2cmdline.h#L181-L183), `<memory.h>` is only included if the `HAVE_MEMORY_H` macro is defined and not equal to 0. A quick [search](https://github.com/chrsigg/par2tbb/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=HAVE_MEMORY_H) yields no occurrences in the repository code where that macro is defined. Is that a standard macro or something?

Comment: It's defined in the makefile written by `./configure` as far as I remember.

Comment: Have you tried removing lines 181 and 183 from [`par2cmdline.h`](https://github.com/chrsigg/par2tbb/blob/master/par2cmdline.h) and recompiling?